# Sql Server not returning fraction digits

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to get the average ocurrences of a value in a data history.
In order to accomplish this I'm running the query:

`SELECT ROUND(COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT ChairID),10)
  FROM Chair 
  WHERE xyz= 1`

The query returns 1, but it should return 1.0500000000.

Running

`SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Chair 
    WHERE xyz = 1`

Returns 21

And running

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ChairID)
  FROM Chair 
  WHERE xyz=1`

Returns 20.

So the first query should return 1.05.

I think the problem is the format in which the server returns the data. I'm using Visual Studio with a local database. Any suggestions how to solve that issue?

Comment: `SELECT ROUND((COUNT(*)*1.0)/COUNT(DISTINCT ChairID),10)`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `COUNT()` returns an integer value. One trick to make it non-int is to multiply by `1.0`.

```
SELECT ROUND( COUNT(*) / (COUNT(DISTINCT ChairID) * 1.0), 10)
FROM Chair 
WHERE xyz = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing integer division and that why getting integer as result. Convert one of the value to Decimal to get results in decimal.

```
SELECT CAST( COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(20))  / COUNT(DISTINCT ChairID) 
FROM Chair 
WHERE xyz= 1
```

Also use CAST for conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The `COUNT()` always returns an integer value, since it represents a count of rows. When you do math with integers in SQL Server, the result is always an integer (sum, rest, multiplications and divisions). Converting the value after doing the division will yield no difference. You should convert any part of the division into a data type that uses decimals, like `DECIMAL` or `FLOAT`.

You can write `CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2), COUNT(*)) / COUNT(DISTINCT ChairID)` or, as a trick, you can multiply either value with `1.0` (which is a double) and the result will be treated as a double `COUNT(*) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT ChairID)`.